# return user object in a oauth flow

Tags: python, reactjs, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am currently working on the oauth flow and am stuck how to pass an user object back to my SPA app.

The flow steps are below

1)SPA app makes a login request to my backend. (should this be get
or post?)

2)Backend constructs the authorize URL and redirects to
the auth provider.
3)user completes authentication and the
authentication provider does a callback to my backend with a valid
authorization code.
4)Backend then parses the code and exchanges
the code with token. This token will have the necessary attributes
to construct a user object.
5)I am stuck at this step on how to
pass this user object to my client SPA app since at this time i have
to do a redirect?.  Am i thinking right on the steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SPA security is a deep topic but the 2021 recommendations are to store OAuth data in strongly encrypted SameSite cookies for most scenarios.

**WEBSITE MODEL**

You are using a website architecture for the SPA currently, where the content delivery and OAuth code are mixed together. You can solve your problem like this:

- Write one or more HTTP-Only Secure AES256 encrypted SameSite cookies after login - containing the data the SPA will need
- SPA then calls GET /userinfo to 'reflect cookies' and receive what it needs
- You may need to use SameSite=lax to prevent the cookie being dropped after a redirect
- On logout the back end should expire these cookies

**BACK END FOR FRONT END**

For a more state-of-the-art solution, it is possible for the SPA to implement OAuth in an API driven manner, to better separate web and API concerns. These resources show how to do this with simple code and best benefits:

- [Tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/back-end-for-front-end/)
- [Code](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/code/spa/src/oauth/oauthClient.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So you are saying that on step 5, i encrypt my cookie in my backend and send it to SPA?

Comment: Yes - that's the usual solution after a web back end completes a login and before the redirect. The SPA can then send the cookie to the back end after the redirect has completed, to ask for userinfo from the cookie.

Comment: what benefit does encryption offer other than someone peaking at the cookie to see the value? If i want to store a value thats not  critical (such as user_id) does it make sense to encrypt?

Comment: The encryption is important for secure cookies used to access back end data - these are always encrypted in technologies such as Java Spring Boot, .Net Core etc - which issue `auth cookies` after handling OAuth responses. If you are not using the cookie as a data access credential then encryption may be less essential.